# How to invoke this method of two parameters?

Tags: scala

I am playing around with `foreach` style methods, and created myself this method which appears to be difficult to invoke:

```
scala> def fun(i: Int => Unit, j: Int => Unit) {
     | i(1)
     | j(2)
     | }
fun: (i: Int => Unit, j: Int => Unit)Unit
```

My numerous attempts have failed to create a valid call.

What could be a grammatically valid call to `fun`?

Comment: for example: `fun({x => println(x)}, {y => println(y)})`

Comment: thank you @om-nom-nom ... I got it now

Comment: this should also work: `fun(println,println)`. It's the same as `fun(println(_),println(_))`, which is just syntactic sugar for `fun(x => println(x),y => println(y))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit and wordy example could be:

```
fun({x => println(x)}, {y => println(y)})
```

But actually you can shorten a lot of code I've written (as @PabloFalabella [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969438/how-to-invoke-this-method-of-two-parameters/17971284#comment26268619_17969438)) and write something like:

```
fun(println,println)
```

This should work fine not only with println, but with any other function (well, as long as it matches signature):

```
def fun(i: (Int,Int) => Unit, j: Int => Unit) { i(1, 2); j(2) }
def printSum(x: Int, y: Int) = println(x + y)

scala> fun(printSum, println)
3
2
```